# Copy/Paste cells & value with property

Tags: c#, excel

I want to copy/paste range at worksheet including the values/property(Strikethrough) in the cells to another new workbook.
I can't set this property at new sheet. Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` I cant copy this property like in the picture.  How can I do it. 3 line in 1 cell with different property

```
public void WriteCellWithFont(int i, int j , _Excel.Range cell)
{
    i++;
    j++;
    ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 = cell.Value2;
    ws.Cells[i,j].Font.Strikethrough = true;
}
```

[image: this problem picture]

Answer (score 0):

Try with PasteSpecial. Its like normal way of we use to keep formatting when paste.

```
// copy
Range cells1 = (Range)worksheet1.Cells[2, 3];
cells1.Copy();

// Paste
Range cells2= (Range)worksheet2.Cells[2, 3];
cells2.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats);
```